# ajaxlink shows blank # Yii

Tags: yii

my ajaxlink shows `#` instead of the link. I tried using `chtml::link`, and that displayed it correctly.

```
 <?php 
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink("<img alt=".$data->text."
    src=".Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath."/images/".$data->img)." 
        title=".$data->text." height=100px width=100px/>",
    Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action',array('id'=>$data->id)),
    array(
        "type" => "post",
        "data" => "js:{ids:$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('chck-id')}",
         "update" => "#grid"));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [ajaxLink](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1196) function

```
public static function ajaxLink($text,$url,$ajaxOptions=array(),$htmlOptions=array())
{
    if(!isset($htmlOptions['href']))
        $htmlOptions['href']='#';
    $ajaxOptions['url']=$url;
    $htmlOptions['ajax']=$ajaxOptions;
    self::clientChange('click',$htmlOptions);
    return self::tag('a',$htmlOptions,$text);
}
```

As you see href comes from htmlOptions. The right code will be:

```
CHtml::ajaxLink("<img alt='".$data->text."'
src='".Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath."/images/".$data->img)."' 
    title='".$data->text."' height=100px width=100px/>",
'',
array(
    "type" => "post",
    "data" => "js:{ids:$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('chck-id')}",
     "update" => "#grid"
),array(
    'href'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action',array('id'=>$data->id))
));
```

Comment: didnt change anything. When i hover I can see the data->text. The images is there as well but the url isn't

Comment: and yii app createurl is not an htmloption...?!

Comment: sigh no doesn't work... maybe it's some other reason

Comment: i have just checked this, it works, show generated html souce

Comment: <a href="#" id="yt0"><img src="/yii/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/zinogy/assets/899f683a/image.png" height="100px" width="100px/"></a>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50978/discussion-between-alex-and-user3232194)

Answer (score 0):

Hope your other approach worked! But you could try repeating the link for both `url` and `href` like this.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink("<img alt='" . $data->text . "'
  src='" . Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath . "/images/" . $data->img) . "' 
  title='" . $data->text . "' height=100px width=100px/>", 
  Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action', array('id' => $data->id)),
  array(
    "type" => "post",
    "data" => "js:{ids:$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('chck-id')}",
    "update" => "#grid"
  ), array(
    'href' => Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action', array('id' => $data->id))
  )
);
```